# Remove HTML tags + content

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

OK, as simple as it sounds I still can't figure out how to do it (and imagine I've even decided to change language for that).

So, I've got either simple text or text containing some tags (**note**:some may not be considered as *valid* html tags, e.g. `<ref>`) and I want to remove ALL tags AND their content.

Tried with Nokogiri's `.search("//text()").text` but it's still far from what I need.

Ideas?

---

**P.S.** I'm looking for a bullet-proof, 100% working solution, so RegEx is rather out of the question...

---

**SAMPLE INPUT/OUTPUT**

```
One <!-- Two -->Three
```

Should return `One Three`.

```
This is <a href='#'>some Text</a>
```

Should return `This is`.

```
Even more <ref name='tag'>reference</ref><br>text
```

Should return `Even more text`.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input/output.

Comment: @JustinWood Have a look at my updated question.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon regex would solve this issues, trying Nokogiri seems like an overkill, I would post my regex answer

Comment: This is a text file, not HTML? So the text you want is not contained in *any* tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this with Nokogiri, you'll have to use the `DocumentFragment` class because the text is not a valid HTML or XML document.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(text)

puts doc.xpath("text()")
```

This gives you the output you specified.

Answer (score 2):

Nokogiri seems to be an overkill for the problem at hand, I would use a regex to solve it as below

```
input = "One <!-- Two -->Three"
input.gsub(/(\<.+\>)/) 
#=> "One Three"

input = "This is <a href='#'>some Text</a>"
input.gsub(/(\<.+\>)/, "")
#=> "This is "

input = "Even more <ref name='tag'>reference</ref><br>text"
input.gsub(/(\<.+\>)/, "")
#=> "Even more text"
```

Demonstration on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/iOQGHnOxt2)